# Canonisation candidate: proper NTP config for a small server pool

Tags: discussion, canonical

I'm quite taken by
[Proper NTP configuration for a few servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/655027/proper-ntp-configuration-for-a-few-servers)
, though I must admit to a (small) hand in the refinement process.  The OP
has put together an answer that reads well and synthesises a lot of
best-practice guidance.  So my question is twofold:

1. Is *at what point should I stop NTP sync'ing all my servers to community
   time sources, establish an internal timeserver pool, and sync the rest of
   my servers to those* a suitable question for canonisation?  And if so
2. Does this particular example of that question contain enough goodness to
   make the question a candidate for canonisation?

Comment: Is this really not a published best practice for Linux?  In Windows-land, the tiered time sync approach has been the MS recommendation for as long as I've been in this career.  I guess I assumed it was the same in Linux-land as well.

Comment: @HopelessN00b an excellent point.  If you can find a respected guide that makes that explicit recommendation for us benighted Free Software types, I'd really like to see it.